# Is it possible to link a random html site with node javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Is it possible to link a *random site* with **node.js**, when I say that, Is it possible to link it with only a URL, if not then I'm guessing it's having the file.html inside the javascript directory. I really wanna know if it's possible because the html is not mine and I can't add the line of code to link it with js that goes something like (not 100% sure) `<src = file.html>`

I tried doing `document = require('./page.html');` and `('./page')` but it didn't work and when I removed the .html at the end of require it would say module not found

My keypoint is that the site shows player count on some servers, and I wanna get that number by linking it with js and then using it in some code which I have the code to (tested in inspect element console) but I don't know how to link it properly to JS.

If you wanna take a look at the site here it is: https://portal.srbultras.info/#servers

If you have any ideas how to link a stranger's html with js, i'd really appreciate to hear it!

Comment: When you tried it yourself, did you have any issues?

Comment: Yeah it says module not found with './file' but with './file.html' it's SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: May you share that effort as a [mcve]?

Comment: document = require('./Basebuilder.html');
-------
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
------
But with
document = require('./Basebuilder');
_------------
MODULE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Please update the question rather than post code in a comment

Comment: Also why are you importing an HTML page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `require` HTML files unless you use something like Webpack with [`html-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader), but even in this case you can only `require` local files. What you can do, however, is to send an HTTP Request to the website. This way you get the same HTML your browser receives whenever you open a webpage. After that you will have to parse the HTML in order to get the data you need. The [`jsdom`](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) package can be used for both steps:

```js
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

JSDOM.fromURL('https://portal.srbultras.info/')
  .then(({ window: { document }}) => {
    const servers = Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll('#servers tbody>tr')
    ).map(({ children }) => {
      const name = children[3].textContent;

      const [ip, port] = children[4]
        .firstElementChild
        .textContent
        .split(':');

      const [playersnum, maxplayers] = children[5]
        .lastChild
        .textContent
        .split('/')
        .map(n => Number.parseInt(n));
      
      return { name, ip, port, playersnum, maxplayers };
    });

    console.log(servers);

    /* Your code here */
  });
```

However, grabbing the server information from a random website is not really what you want to do, because there is a way to get it directly from the servers. Counter Strike 1.6 servers seem to use the GoldSrc / Source Server Protocol that lets us retrieve information about the servers. You can read more about the protocol [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries), but we are just going to use the [`source-server-query`](https://github.com/dsyomichev/source-server-query) package to send queries:

```js
const query = require('source-server-query');

const servers = [
  { ip: '51.195.60.135', port: 27015 },
  { ip: '51.195.60.135', port: 27017 },
  { ip: '185.119.89.86', port: 27021 },
  { ip: '178.32.137.193', port: 27500 },
  { ip: '51.195.60.135', port: 27018 },
  { ip: '51.195.60.135', port: 27016 }
];

const timeout = 5000;

Promise.all(servers.map(server => {
  return query
    .info(server.ip, server.port, timeout)
    .then(info => Object.assign(server, info))
    .catch(console.error);
})).then(() => {
  query.destroy();
  console.log(servers);

  /* Your code here */
});
```

##### Update

`servers` is just a normal JavaScript array consisting of objects that describe servers, and you can see its structure when it is logged into the console after the information has been received, so it should not be hard to work with. For example, you can access the `playersnum` property of the third server in the list by writing `servers[2].playersnum`. Or you can loop through all the servers and do something with each of them by using functions like [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), or just a normal for loop.

But note that in order to use the data you get from the servers, you have to put your code in the callback function passed to the `then` method of `Promise.all(...)`, i.e. where `console.log(servers)` is located. This has to do with the fact that it takes some time to get the responses from the servers, and for that reason server queries are normally asynchronous, meaning that the script continues execution even though it has not received the responses yet. So if you try to access the information in the global scope instead of the callback function, it is not going to be there just yet. You should read about JavaScript Promises if you want to understand how this works.

Another thing you may want to do is to filter out the servers that did not respond to the query. This can happen if a server is offline, for example. In the solution I have provided, such servers are still in the `servers` array, but they only have the `ip` and `port` properties they had originally. You could use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in order to get rid of them. Do you see how? Tell me if you still need help.

Comment: Hey @aweebit Thanks for the answer I deeply appreciate it I couldn't find the answer anywhere, but in the server quary, how should i get the `playersnum` or `map`?

I tried quary.info.playersnum
info.playersnum
server.info.playersnum
server.playersnum

Comment: I have updated my answer to address your question. Please tell me if you still need help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What i did was at the bottom "then" added value so it was like `  })).then((values) => {` and then i did values[0].playersnum Thanks!